# Update in SQL from a select statement to another table

Tags: sql-update

I have a select query and working fine. Now the output of this query I want to update in another table.

Question is - output by a select query, aggregate stuff, I want to keep in another table. How can I do that?

```
SELECT  
    CostID as CostID,
    SUM(Budget) as Budget,
    SUM(TD) as TD,
    SUM(Forecast) as Forecast,

FROM    
    A

GROUP BY 

    TD,
    Forecast,
    CostID,
    Cost,

)
```

I want to update `CostID`, Sum of `Budget`, Sum of `TD`, `Forecast` in another table.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a key in the other table where you can join your select statement above?

If there is a key then you can just write an update statement:

```
    UPDATE        SOURCE_TABLE
    SET           SOURCE_TABLE.Cost_ID = NEW_QUERY.Cost_ID
                  SOURCE_TABLE.Budget = NEW_QUERY.Budget
                  SOURCE_TABLE.TD = NEW_QUERY.TD
                  SOURCE_TABLE.Forecast = NEW_QUERY.Forecast
    FROM          SOURCE_TABLE
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT        CostID as CostID,
                      SUM(Budget) as Budget,
                      SUM(TD) as TD,
                      SUM(Forecast) as Forecast
        FROM          A
        GROUP BY      TD,
                      Forecast,
                      CostID,
                      Cost
    )       AS NEW_QUERY
    ON            SOURCE_TABLE.joining_key = NEW_QUERY.joining_key
```